# Long beep after formatting an Acer X1430 desktop

Tags: hard-drive, boot, memory

I booted up this machine using a Fedora Live USB stick, did a backup and proceeded to format the hard drive using GParted. Opened the disk tray and inserted my Windows 7 installation disk. Everything was fine. Then I opened the session menu and chose "shutdown". The computer proceeded to turn off correctly. I then disconnected my hard drive, the USB stick and then turned it on again. Bam. A loud, continuous beep keeps coming out from the machine. It was working completely fine 5 seconds ago and now the internet tells me my motherboard just died.

I tried booting up without any devices attached, with the same hardware that was connected before I shut it down, etc., but nothing seems to help.

What in the world just happened? Is it really dead? Did my hard drive died? Is it some sort of formatting-protection on this acer models?

Comment: Vote to close as problem can no longer be reproduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved now.

Just in case somebody wonders, I just opened it, took off the RAM, blew the dust a little and put it back in. Then it booted properly. Weird.

**Update to further expand this answer:**

I have done a little research and found out that some motherboards do not like some RAM modules on certain slots, and it's recommended to place the first stick (specially if there's only one, like in this case) on the outermost slot away from the processor; and that's what I did and it's working fine now.